# Bluetooth : How to suppress a system generated Default Bluetooth pairing request popup

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth

BlueGiga Tool / Android App:

The BlueGiga tool initiates a Popup (Pairing Request) request on the Android App Screen asking permission to Pair with the device.
I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this Popup/Dialog every time when connect with a device.
A reference image of the popup has been attached. Any idea and suggestions are welcome.

Thankyou!!

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R70Dj.jpg)